# Can I create Facebook Life Events via OpenGraph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

Is it possible to create a Facebook Life Event via Open Graph API? Is it?

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible. If it's not in roadmap and it's not in the documentation (documentation should reflect the latest changes to the API now, it's dynamically updated), then it's not available.